# If I delete my iOS app, would it also delete the values I saved in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have an iOS project in which I save two string values in `NSUserDefaults` for app settings. If I deleted the app from my device, would the saved values be deleted as well? Or does it need to be deleted manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as this values are only saved locally in NSUserDefaults, when you remove the app, all of this values will be lost. If you need persistance, check for iCloud saving settings.

Comment: I see. Just needed to verify because I wasn't sure. Thanks